# Best Reading App for Personal PDFs which Remembers Last Location on an Android Tablet

Tags: reading

I like the Kindle app (it remembers the last location) and the Adobe PDF app (it can view PDFs), but I'm looking for an app for my tablet which remembers the last location and can view PDFs.

Answer (score 2):

I've done a little research myself and [Aldiko](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aldiko.android&hl=en) looks excellent. I'm especially looking forward to using it on a tablet.

Answer (score 2):

[ezPDF Reader](https://market.android.com/details?id=udk.android.reader) is also very good, supports bookmarks, and will reopen a file wherever you closed it.